# SQL : Im tring to work out, how to return last action per member

Tags: sql-server

```
Id     Mshp_Id    Action
1      9029       Register
2      9029       Create CV
3      8476       Register
4      8476       Create CV
5      8476       JOB SEARCH
```

I want to return the two membership ID's and their latest action.
so what would be left is ID 2 AND 5 ONLY.

Comment: What is your SQL SERVER version?

Comment: I dont know, I dont work in the IT department, im trying to do this in Powerbi which uses SQL.

Comment: You are probably looking for a SELECT with a GROUP BY and a MAX statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, you can use [LAST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT ID,
    ,mshp_id
    ,action
FROM (
    SELECT *,LAST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY mshp_id 
                              ORDER BY ID 
                              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                              AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
            ) last_val
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
    ) a
WHERE id = last_val
ORDER BY ID
```

[***Check Demo here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8bb76d82f9620d22d88765cf399f138)

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I will try as soon as I am able as other things have cropped up. I will let you know if this is a succes. cheers mate!

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again for this bit of code, helped me out, bit of tweeking here and there, but I finally finished the problem. Chers again!

Answer (score 0):

Last action per member can be fetched through the following ways

**Solution 1:**

```
select Id, Mshp_Id, Action from (
select *, row_number() over (partition by Mshp_Id order by id desc) r from user_action
) a
where a.r = 1
order by id
```

**Solution 2**

```
select u.* from user_action u
join (select Mshp_Id, max(id) id from user_action 
group by Mshp_Id ) a
on a.Mshp_Id = u.Mshp_Id and a.id = u.id 
order by u.id
```

Good luck with your work !

Comment: @ prince, thanks for this. I agree, you cant ever learn all there is to know unless you get stuck from time to time. Thanks for this though, will let you know if it is useful.

Comment: Your solution provided me with ideas on how I can make another project of mine work. So, you have helped me twice there, cheers! :-)